# gethostbyname returning ip address 127.0.0.1

Tags: c, linux, networking

I want to get the ip address of my current system through following code snippet:

```
if(gethostname(src_host, sizeof(src_host)) < 0)  {
    printf("Error in getting host name...\n");
    return 0;
}   else    {
    printf("Host name = %s\n", src_host);
    if((src_hst = gethostbyname(src_host)) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot resolve host...\n");
        return 0;
    }else   {
        ip->ip_src = (*(struct in_addr *)src_hst->h_addr_list[0]);
        printf("Ip Address=%s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));
    }

}
```

But in output I am getting 12.0.0.1 that is local ip address ( I am new to networing) I want 172.23.1.182 defined in eth0.

Can anyone please help?

```
lovebird@lovebird:~/prog/icmp$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:eb:69:71:7f:c0  
          inet addr:172.23.1.182  Bcast:172.23.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::62eb:69ff:fe71:7fc0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1831227 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1362960 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1549696322 (1.5 GB)  TX bytes:296632333 (296.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9757 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9757 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:944058 (944.0 KB)  TX bytes:944058 (944.0 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:f3:95:b4:23:69  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: Which host string are you using? Have you tried walking all of the returned addresses?

Comment: Check your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Although traditionally a machine's own hostname and address were the first entry in its `/etc/hosts`, it has been a long time since it was safe to assume that.  These days, machines' own host names are not necessarily recorded in `/etc/hosts` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getifaddrs` which will return the address assigned to the interface. `gethostname` is basically a DNS request, which is served by the entry from your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Dunno why this was downvoted.  Given that the question is tagged "linux", this is a fine answer, albeit brief.

Comment: Note that `getifaddrs()` returns a linked list of *all* the host's network addresses, of which there will normally be *at least* two.  You need to look through these various results to find an address that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation.
My /etc/hosts file contains the following entries for Dell-Laptop:

```
127.0.1.1   Dell-Laptop
192.168.1.8 Dell-Laptop # Tony's Dell Inspiron Laptop
```

A small mod to your code would get both:

```
if(gethostname(src_host, sizeof(src_host)) < 0)  {
    printf("Error in getting host name...\n");
    return 0;
}   else    {
    printf("Host name = %s\n", src_host);
    if((src_hst = gethostbyname(src_host)) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot resolve host...\n");
        return 0;
    }else   {
        // ip->ip_src = (*(struct in_addr *)src_hst->h_addr_list[0]);
        // printf("Ip Address=%s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));
        for(idx=0;src_hst->h_addr_list[idx];idx++)
        {
            printf("Ip Address=%s\n", 
             inet_ntoa((*(struct in_addr *)src_hst->h_addr_list[idx])));
        }
    }

}
```